# mysql query mass increment

Tags: mysql

I have a large table of data with a new field added called `uniq_id` what I am looking for is a query I can run that will update and increment this field for each row, without having to write a script to do this.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What other columns does the table have? If you define the new column with [`AUTO_INCREMENT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) MySQL will fill it with sequential values starting from 1. There's a catch though: the column has to be a key, or at least a part of the key (see the [documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html) for details). If you don't have a primary key in the table already, you can simply do this:

```
alter table MyTable add uniq_id int auto_increment, add primary key (uniq_id);
```

If you can't change the keys in the table and just want to fill the values of the new column as a one-off thing, you can use this `update` statement:

```
update MyTable set uniq_id = (@count := coalesce(@count+1, 1));
```

([`coalesce`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) returns its first non-null argument; it effectively establishes the value of the column for the first row.)

Answer (score 1):

somethink like that (hard to make better without your structure)

```
SET @rank = 0;
UPDATE <your table> JOIN (SELECT @rank:= @rank+ 1 AS rank, <your pk> FROM <your table> ORDER BY rank DESC)
AS order USING(<your pk>) SET <your table>.uniq_id = order.rank;
```

or easier

```
SET @rank=0;
UPDATE <your table> SET uniq_id= @rank:= (@rank+1) ORDER BY <anything> DESC;
```